Is ISIT conference on Linguistics and applied linguistics fake?
Is this conference fake? Or is it just not popular? https://isit.org.in/event/index.php?id=2385102
I am a PhD student. I just found this conference and applied for me to do something useful while traveling in Summer. But it seems really weird to me. The name of the contact person cannot be found in any academia. The domain of the website is in India, the country code of the phone number too

Looks pretty sus, but we don't answer questions about individual journals/papers/conferences, or else we'd be over-run with that kind of question.

The About page is... unusual.  "The ISIT-forum constitutes of professional wizards and overseas technical leaders who have left no stones unturned to reinforce the field of science, engineering and technology." "Beside this ISIT is collaborated with leading publisher of world to expose the innovation of its wizards. Last but not the least [ISIT] is one among the leading institutes of the globe to inculcate technical revolution among scholars, brilliants, geniuses and wizards of different country."

ISIT is a legitimate conference in information theory. ISIT on Linguistics on the other hand…
